# fastest way to convert array to multiline string

Tags: c#, arrays, string, c#-4.0, export-to-csv

what is the most efficient way to export array elements into a .csv excel file? Now I am doing like this, but it is very slow. Thank you for all your support.

```
int FrameWidth = 640;
int FrameHeight = 480;
Int16[] Values;  // 640 x 480, 307200 elements

/*
.. processing ...... 
*/

//Exporting Values to .csv file
string string2csv = null;
for (int y = 0; y < FrameHeight; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < FrameWidth; x++)
    {
        string2csv = string2csv + Values[y * FrameWidth + x] + ";";
    }
    string2csv = string2csv + "\n";
}
File.WriteAllText("string2csv.csv", string2csv);
```

Comment: One option would be to use `StringBuilder` instead of `+`.

Comment: Use the String.Join Method [more information here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @DriesVB Note that `String.Join` uses a `StringBuilder` internally.

Comment: Don't do it by hand. Use a library like [CSV Helper](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"most efficient" wil take trial and error, but one easy alternative is to use `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder string2csv = new StringBuilder();
for (int y = 0; y < FrameHeight; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < FrameWidth; x++)
    {
        string2csv.Append(Values[y * FrameWidth + x] + ";");
    }
    string2csv.Append("\n");
}
```

Adding strings using `+` allocates memory for a new string, then copies the contents of the two strings into the new memory.  `StringBuilder` pre-allocates a buffer in memory and adds characters to the buffer, extending it as necessary.  There's much less memory allocation and copying when adding lots of strings.

That may be "fast enough".  Other than that, you'd need to get a decent profiler to see where your code is spending the most time and attack that part.  It's entirely possible that your "processing..." block is the bottleneck, not the CSV output.

Comment: You don't even need to do that. He's building up a string of the contents of the file when he could just write to the file directly.

Comment: @JeffMercado Not sure that would be more efficient

Comment: For the purpose of optimization is very important to set an initial capacity for the stringbuilder according to the size of the input array (ca 5 * 307K bytes).

Comment: @Frisbee: How so? File streams are buffered by default. How would generating all the data then writing it be more efficient than writing the data as it's generated.

Comment: Yes, if I do it this way: File.WriteAllText("string2csv.csv", string.Join(";", Values)); it is super fast :) but only 1 long row in excel.

Comment: @JeffMercado OP can always just test

Comment: You may all be right, but I suspect that the string appending and whatever is in  "processing..." far outweigh the extra memory allocation.

Comment: @atteee I think what @Jeff means is that you should write to a `StreamWriter` rather than a `StringBuilder`

Comment: @atteee `string.Join` is faster because it uses `StringBuilder` internally.

Comment: @JeffMercado: hmm, I always thought it's faster to do as least I/O as possible... how does doing thousands of write operations to a file stream make it faster than buffering it all to memory, and doing a single write to the file stream? Albeit, I realize the write operations are buffered (somewhat)...

Comment: The amount of I/O is going to be about the same either way - the only difference is whether you do I/O within the loop or build up a big string in memory and dump it all out at once.

Comment: @code4life: If unbuffered, then yes, it would be less efficient. But as I mentioned, file streams are buffered. Writing out to a file either on demand or in blocks should be roughly the same assuming it's not manually flushed.

Answer (score 3):

One alternative is to combine `File.WriteAllLines` and `string.Join`;

```
File.WriteAllLines ("test.txt", 
    Values.Select((x,i) => new {x, i})
          .GroupBy(x => x.i / FrameWidth)
          .Select(grp => string.Join(";", grp.Select(y => y.x)))
);
```

It will select all elements along with the index in the array.
It will then group the values by row (calculated by dividing the index by the number of columns).
The grouped values are then joined using `;` into a string per row, and the rows are all fed into File.WriteAllLines.

Comment: StringBuilder seams to be the fastest, with 27ms, then Joachim's with 38ms, my solution 21 496ms :)  I am very very thankful for all your comments! You guys are all great!